# SSH or Remote filesystem mounting

Tags: ssh, vim, terminal, filesystems

In a situation where you spend the majority of your time in the terminal and Vim/Emacs/other command-line editors, what are the pro's and con's of working via SSH or by mounting a remote filesystem using tools like SSHFS and AFP?

I currently work over SSH, but I find it heinous to maintain dot/rc-files across multiple hosts, so I've considere changing my workflow. Anyone with insight on the matter?

Note: Yeah, I presume this will get closed off by the mods fast enough, but I am genuinely curious.

Comment: I'll bite and throw the first stone: primarily opinion-based (but indeed interesting question).

Answer (score 3):

As hardware has become cheaper and more ubiquitous (and now even tablets and smart phones play in that space), distributed configurations are a fact of life. Many people use a GitHub repository as their configuration hub, I personally prefer syncing with [Unison File Synchronizer](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/). In any way, there are many workable solutions out there.

Mounting remote file systems is great for mass-editing configuration, e.g. to update DNS settings for all production servers. But usually sysadmin tasks don't just consist of edits, but also require other actions (like restarting a service). This may be workable in Emacs, where you can easily get a shell within the editor, but in Vim, this usually means opening a separate SSH connection to the system. That (and because I prefer to have a complete record of the system changes in the shell command history) means I choose local editing for those tasks. (And those tasks are usually small, so I don't need my full Vim configuration, anyway.)

Comment: I guess I'll keep huge project folders mounted and then dip in through SSH if I need to apply system-wide tasks. As of now, I am just a puny underling and don't do much administrative work, so local mounting seems like my best fit :) Thanks yet again Ingo! PS: Nice hat

Answer (score 1):

Set up NFS on your server and mount it locally at each boot or when needed.

You'll be able to use all your local tools for edition, etc... just as if files were locally stored. Also when a file is savec, it is stored on the server.

SSH is best option but for comfort try NFS.